# Control the speed on my game?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

How can I control the speed of my player? I'm using `didSimulatePhysics()` method for movement:

```
   if(([self childNodeWithName:@"hero"].position.x >= 180)
   &&
   (self.touchedHero == YES)
    && _canMove ==YES){

    [[self childNodeWithName:@"hero"]setPosition:CGPointMake(180, [self childNodeWithName:@"hero"].position.y)];

    [self.world setPosition:CGPointMake(self.world.position.x-5, self.world.position.y)];
```

But this method depend in the device performance, and when running my app on an iOs device the speed is very unstable, sometimes it go very fast and sometimes slow down, how can I control this speed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to consider (or not consider) frame-rate independence, or changing the way you structure the game or physics calculations.  More importantly, this might be a good time to start eliminating major inefficiencies in your code... this is a "starter" list of questions to ask yourself:

- How are you organizing your objects? Are you just looping through everything and performing physics calculations and collision detection on everything, regardless of conditions that would make those calculations unnecessary?
- Are you partitioning objects into a spatial tree, or just looping through all of them (most importantly for collision detection)?
- How many objects do you have? How many do you need? Can anything be removed from the game without sacrificing your desired user experience?
- Are you performing physics calculations for off-screen objects?
- Any serious algorithmic flaws in any of your physics or logic calculations? Anything that could be improved by orders of magnitude?
- Are you storing objects in a sensible way? Not quite as immediately effective as the items above, but you could consider object pooling for example.
- Are you using any Objective-C code that could be replaced with C code inside expensive loop bodies?  (C function calls execute in 2 CPU cycles, whereas Objective-C messages in ARC execute in 9 cycles - this is NOT the first thing you should look at, but could be worth considering. A 4.5x speedup isn't too shabby if you're dealing with a lot of objects - but this likely isn't your bottleneck).

[This good post on learn-cocos2d.com](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/10/game-engine-multiply-delta-time-or-not/) goes into more detail about the FPS issue, with iOS in mind.

[This good post on gafferongames.com](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) goes into detail on various ways to handle timestep updates. An interesting read, but you'll want to look at your data structures & algorithms first for any obvious stuff before getting too occupied with your timestep.